# Code Blocks exit(0) error?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm learning c++ and was using Visual Studios but I switched to code blocks today and am having trouble. My Compiler is MinGW if that's important. Anyway I made a practice program that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Int main()
{
Int x;
cin >> x;
If(x == 1)
Exit(0)
Return 0;
}
```

When I build it I get an error on the line containing Exit(0). Why is this? Also, how do I get the build/debug toolbars at the bottom to reappear?

Comment: You are missing semicolon after Exit(0)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There's no `Int`. There's no `If`. There's no `Return`. There's no `Exit`. `exit` is in `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: What's with the capitalization?  int/if/exit/return etc. are lowercase words...

Comment: What weird implementation is this?

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>   

int main(){
   using namespace std;
   int x;
   cin >> x;
   if(x == 1) {exit(0);}
   return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Do us the favour and move that using namespace INTO main and change `Exit` towards `exit`. And while you are at it, add `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: Does Not Compile. "error: ‘Exit’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Exit needs to be lower case.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ are case sensitive. This causes a number of problems with your code (not just `Exit` vs. `exit`).

In addition to that, as a simple rule for C++, forget that `exit` exists anyway. It doesn't execute destructors properly, which breaks RAII. If you haven't studied C++ enough to know what RAII is yet, just trust me that this is a really *bad* thing to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if(x == 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // return something different from the normal exit
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to exit from main, just use `return`, as I've changed the code above. If you need to exit from somewhere else due to a truly *dire* emergency (e.g., you've detected such a massive problem that even trying to shut down cleanly is likely to destroy the user's data) you probably want to use `abort()`. Otherwise, you probably want to throw an exception, which will propagate back to `main`, and exit from there (after executing destructors properly).